# Missing metrics when programmatically creating a circuitbreaker

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

I want to define a circuitbreak with a programming approach so I did:

```
@Configuration
public class MyCircuitBreakerConfig {

@Bean
public CircuitBreakerRegistry myRegistry() {
    CircuitBreakerRegistry registry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.ofDefaults();
    registry.circuitBreaker("mycircuit", circuitConfig());
    return registry;
}
```

Problem is that, even though it works correctly, I get the following in metrics:

```
"components" : {
"circuitBreakers" : {
  "status" : "UNKNOWN"
}
```

While, if I define it in my properties file:

```
resilience4j:
 circuitbreaker:
      configs:
        myconfig:
          ...
      instances:
       mycircuit:
          base-config: myconfig
```

I can see it. What could the problem be?
I'm using the resilience4j-spring-boot2 dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not create your own CircuitBreakerRegistry.
The Spring Boot AutoConfiguration creates an instance which you should use. If you need it, just inject (autowire) the existing CircuitBreakerRegistry into your code.

You can override the defaults as follows

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
    configs:
        default:
            slidingWindowSize: 100
            permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 10
            waitDurationInOpenState: 10000
            failureRateThreshold: 60
            eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
```

Comment: I would just suffice to set the defaults..how to do that?

Comment: @phate I don't think you can configure a circuitbreaker in the application config with pure defaults. At least, I couldn't work out how to do it. You have to overwrite one property (with its default value).

Comment: Will it pick it up from the yaml if I already have application.properties?